# Aparece #Name? cuando le doy un valor predeterminado a un text box en Access

Tags: base-de-datos, formularios, ms-access, vb6

Tengo un formulario en el cual tengo un campo de texto donde se ingresa la fecha de trabajo del usuario el cual por default quisiera que mostrara la fecha del dia actual. Investigando en internet encontré la funcion "Fecha()" que hace precisamente esto.

El problema es que cuando me voy a ponerle esta funcion en el valor predeterminado de mi text box e intento ver mi formulario en vista de formulario me aparece el mensaje "#Name?" en lugar de la fecha.

A que se debe esto? O será que la funcion Fecha() no puede manejarse aqui?

Se me hace muy raro porque esta misma funcion ya la habia utilizado en otro form con la misma intencion y si habia funcionado sin problemas aquella vez.

Comment: vb6? access? de cual de todos los lenguajes hablas? y podrias mostrar el codigo que estas usando?? y si es en access (lo que infiero) sera que esta en ingles y la funcion debellamarse en ingles?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Luis!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento debes modificar tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado e investigado, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Este error puede ser por varias causas:

1) El nombre de tu textbox es igual que tu campo. Parece una tontería, pero muchas veces este error simplemente cambiando el nombre del textbox a TXTnombrecampo, siendo nombrecampo el nombre del campo asociado.

2) Asegúrate que la propiedad Origen del Control es correcta, y lo tienes bien enlazado al campo que te interesa.

3) A la hora de nombrar campos en tablas, consultas, formularios e informes, intenta evitar usar palabras que estén reservadas para el sistema como Fecha,Name, y cosas así. Es mucho mejor utilizar nombres de campo como EstaFecha o MiFecha o MiNombre y luego con la propiedad título o con etiquetas en formularios lo dejas bonito y con un texto más adecuado para el usuario.

4) En tu pregunta dices "*...en el cual tengo un campo de texto donde se ingresa la fecha...*". Si el tipo de dato es Texto, cámbialo a Fecha/hora, a ver si así sí te reconoce como valor predeterminado la función `Fecha()`

Mis respuestas son muy vagas, pero prueba a ver si solucionan tu problema.

Comment: Mira que me ha pasado veces y nunca recuerdo esto. Gracias